Re-orient tikz-angles labels that are drawn on a plane so that they are not distorted
I am using the angles library to draw on planes in perspective, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727949/319072.
I am wondering how to make the angle label appear oriented as though it were on the screen plane - like regular text.
For example, in this MWE I want to re-orient the blue theta so that it resembles the red theta, except without changing its location on the screen.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{100}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
            \draw[step=0.2, ultra thin, gray] (-2,-1) grid (3,2);
            \pgflowlevelsynccm
            \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
            \coordinate (A) at (2,1,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (-1,1,0);
            \draw (A) -- (O) -- (B);
            \draw pic[blue,draw,ultra thick,->,angle eccentricity=1.4, angle radius=1cm,"$\theta$"]{angle=A--O--B};
        \end{scope}
        
        % For some reason, after using \pgflowlevelsynccm, we have to reset the coordinates.
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
        \coordinate (A) at (2,1,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (-1,1,0);
        \draw pic[red,draw,ultra thick,->,angle eccentricity=1.4, angle radius=1cm,"$\theta$"]{angle=A--O--B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Interesting, the low level sync is forgotten by PGF/TikZ and the PGF transformation are reset, everything else after it starts with new transformation. That is why the coordinates are not properly defined after \pgflowlevelsync. Your main problem has the same difficulty though. Usually shift only would achieve this, but it can't reset the transformation matrix of the low level sync.

A low level sync is forgotten by PGF/TikZ which is why placing coordinates/nodes after it will not remember the correct position and why shift only doesn't work either.
Here's an attempt at providing a low level shift only which needs \pgflowlevelsynccm do save the transformation it syncs down.
For low level shift only (\pgftransformresetnontranslationslowlevel) these saved entries are inverted and applied: This undoes the low level transformation at the upper level (before it is applied again by the lower level).

Notes:

This only works with exactly one low level syncs.
I'm also trying to fix \pgfmultipartnode which does the remembering of a nodes/coordinates position but it's not as straight forward.

Code
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifpgf@lowlevelsync
\let\orig@pgflowlevelsynccm\pgflowlevelsynccm
\def\pgflowlevelsynccm{%
  \unless\ifpgf@pt@identity
    \pgf@lowlevelsynctrue
    \pgfgettransform\pgflowlevelsynccmentries
    \begingroup % calculate inverse only once
      \pgftransforminvert\pgfgettransform\pgflowlevelsynccmentriesinverse
      \edef\pgf@marshal{\endgroup\def\noexpand\pgflowlevelsynccmentriesinverse{\pgflowlevelsynccmentriesinverse}}%
    \pgf@marshal
  \fi
  \orig@pgflowlevelsynccm}
\makeatletter
\def\pgftransformresetnontranslationslowlevel{%
  \ifpgf@lowlevelsync
    \expandafter\pgftransformresetnontranslationslowlevel@\pgflowlevelsynccmentriesinverse
  \else
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
  \fi}
\def\pgftransformresetnontranslationslowlevel@#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \pgfsettransformentries{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{\pgf@pt@x}{\pgf@pt@y}}
\tikzset{low level shift only/.code=\tikz@addtransform{\pgftransformresetnontranslationslowlevel}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{65}{100}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \draw[step=0.2, ultra thin, gray] (-2,-1) grid (3,2);
% draws correctly, coordinate positions not correct after low level sync:
%  \draw (-1,1) coordinate (B) -- (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (2,1) coordinate (A);
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw (-1,1) coordinate (B) -- (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (2,1) coordinate (A);
  \pic[blue, draw, ultra thick, ->, angle eccentricity=1.4, angle radius=1cm,
    "$\theta$" low level shift only]{angle=A--O--B};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output


Thank you for taking the time to fix this! Just thought I'd drop a comment to emphasize that there should be no comma between the quote "$\theta$" and the low level shift only. (as you did correctly)
